# Using .bashrc to open server files in local app?

Tags: macos, bash, terminal, sublimetext2

I had this working on a previous work server but I no longer work there and never copied my .bashrc so now I've forgotten what I did since it was so long ago.

Basically I ssh onto my server and then do `ide file.txt` and it will use the alias ide to open the file in a local app on my laptop.

So my alias now is:

```
alias ide="/Applications/Sublime\ Text\ 2.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl"
```

I think I was maybe using my IP before but I'm not sure. If it is IP, is there a way to alter it because I am on a laptop and the IP address changes.

Comment: Your quotes aren't balanced. Is that in the actual code, or just a copying error?

Comment: I just didn't copy the closing " when I copied it over here.

Comment: https://www.sublimetext.com/docs/2/osx_command_line.html shows how to use Sublimt Text 2 from the terminal. I don't see an option to display the window on a remote client.

Answer (score 0):

You may have been using the [`rsub`](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/rsub) plugin, which adapts the `rmate` remote editing script from [TextMate](http://www.macromates.com) for use with Sublime, allowing for the editing of files on remote servers using SSH port forwarding/tunneling. It comes with three scripts, written in JavaScript (node.js), Ruby, and bash, and you pick one and copy it to the remote server. The [README](https://github.com/aurora/rmate/blob/master/README.md) in the `rmate-bash` repo describes how to set things up.

---

While I'm at it, I would strongly urge you to check out [Sublime Text 3](http://sublimetext.com/3). Even though it's still marked "beta", it is very stable and certainly as good for production work as is ST2. ST2's development is long done, and no more bugs will be fixed in it - in fact, Jon Skinner is already starting to architect ST4! ST3 has an updated Python 3 [API](http://www.sublimetext.com/docs/3/api_reference.html) and a bunch more features, both under the hood and user-facing. Many plugin authors are now developing just for ST3, and some have even dropped ST2 compatibility altogether because of the differences in the codebases and the API. Others still have ST2 functionality, but aren't developing for it any further, having implemented feature freezes. However, for the time being, lots of plugins work on both versions, including `rsub`, and for those that don't there are often superior versions available for ST3, such as the redesigned [SublimeLinter](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/SublimeLinter) framework.

At any rate, definitely check it out. I've been using it nearly exclusively for over two years now, and haven't had any major problems. Assuming you licensed ST2 (which hopefully you have if you're using it commercially), the license *should* also work with ST3, at least until the final version is released, when you'll have to upgrade. Also, if you're a licensed user, you can try out the [dev builds](http://sublimetext.com/3dev), which have some bleeding-edge features (and bug fixes) not in the public beta builds yet. For example, the public beta is currently Build 3083, while the current dev build is 3095.

Comment: I downloaded ST3 a year or maybe more ago but I never got around to checking it out fully as I never felt like I had the time. It's just one of those things with a huge change in the codebase it's not just, "update and continue" and more like a need to see what's actually changed. I will eventually move on and get into it but just haven't found myself doing it yet.

Comment: As far as the answer goes, it might be possible but I rmate or rsub doesn't sound familiar like I was doing that before.